# NSNumberFormatter for converting to currencies

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I need to create a NSFormatter that takes integer values, and sends them to formatted currencies, but the catch is it must add K, and M for thousands and millions. E.G:

```
130000 -> $130k
12000 -> $12k
10000000 ->$10M
```

It has to be a datatype NSNumberFormatter since I'll be using it to set a property which takes parameter NSNumberFormatter (I'm formatting the axis labels of a graph).

Comment: It's easy enough to set the currency aspect. But to add your k, and M suffixes depending on the number you will need to subclass `NSNumberFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

`NSByteCountFormatter` can help:

```
int number = 100000;

NSString *binaryFormatted = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:number countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleDecimal];
NSLog(@"binaryFormatted: %@", binaryFormatted);

NSString *digits = [binaryFormatted substringToIndex:binaryFormatted.length-3];
NSString *units  = [binaryFormatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(binaryFormatted.length-2, 1)];
NSString *currencyFormatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@%@", digits, units];

NSLog(@"currencyFormatted: %@", currencyFormatted);
```

NSLog output

> binaryFormatted: 100 KB
>   currencyFormatted: $100K